# POST a series of products in Laravel / PHP

Tags: php, laravel, post, request

I'm using **Laravel** to post a series of products. The user can choose a quantity of each product.

Now I'm wondering how I can post a series, but still have the names of the products.

I have tried the following.

> This result gives me an undefined offset error

```
<input name="{{ $products[$product->id] }}" />
```

> This result doesn't include the name, but does make it a series

```
<input name="products[]" />
```

### Any idea how I might end up with an array that's called $products, and has all the products in there by name

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

was not that far away

```
name="products[{{ $product->id }}]"
```

The products array must be defined in html, while the content should be the PHP.